# Oracle JDBC connection pool

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

1) Which implementation of oracle jdbc connection pool is better to use?
(I don't need something special on my project.)

2) Is it a good practice to create a singleton with connection pool?

3) Are the connection pools thread-safe?

For example I'll get:

```
OracleDataSource ods = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
```

I need to create connections in different parts of my backend.

Am I right that I should create OracleDataSource object only once and set necessary parameters?

For example:

```
ods.setURL(URL);
ods.setUser(USER);
ods.setPassword(PASS);
```

How should I provide an access to this connection pool object in other parts of application?
Should I create for this purpose a singleton with connection pool object field?

It's the first time we decided to add connection for DB in this app (some parameters should be stored in DB now). Can you clarify me the point about app server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question lacks context and is impossible to answer as such, it is way to vague

Comment: You could start with http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/changes-report.html

Comment: It may help you to read in the [help] about how to effectively ask on StackOverflow. It's good that you've added what you did, but this post has too many questions. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. You need to narrow this down to a single topic (but you can post more than one question). And don't ask "what's best" or anything that looks like the answer is an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't matter.  Pick one that's easy to use with your app container.
2. Let the app server handle the connection pool.  You shouldn't write it.
3. Pools might be, but the connection itself is not.

Your additional code example:

```
OracleDataSource ods = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
```

You should only do this if you want to guarantee that you can never switch database vendors again.  You're stuck once you write a single line of code that uses Oracle classes.

JDBC is interface based.  It's designed to make it possible to switch databases by exchanging driver JARs.  I would advise that you learn how to do it that way.

Comment: Thank you! I extended the question description after your answer. Can you provide me additional information about my new questions?

Comment: You can use Universal Connnection Pool (UCP) as the connection pool. Refer to UCP guide (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjucp/toc.htm) for more details.